# WordPress email alerts when existing user role changes (don't send emails to new users)

Tags: php, wordpress, email, user-roles

On my WordPress website I use this code in my theme's **functions.php** file to send automatic email to users when their role has been changed. The roles are updated manually  by the administrator.

```
function user_role_update( $user_id, $new_role ) {
        $site_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $to = $user_info->user_email;
        $subject = "Role changed: ".$site_url."";
        $message = "Hello " .$user_info->display_name . " your role has changed on ".$site_url.", congratulations you are now an " . $new_role;
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2);
```

This piece of code works fine, apart from one thing - **new users also receive email notifications about the role change upon registration!** It's very confusing.

Is there a way to avoid sending this email to new users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the time that the user object was created by inspecting `$user_info->user_registered`.

So you could wrap at least the `wp_mail` line of your code in an if block like this to suppress notifications to newly registered users:

```
if ( strtotime ( $user_info->user_registered) < strtotime ('-30 minutes') ) {
  //send email
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So, for example, can I wrap my function into the **if** statement like this?

`if ( strtotime( $user_info->user_registered ) > ( time() - 30 ) ) {...;}`

Comment: Yes. I wanted to test this first to be sure.